# Animated drag and drop to proper (one of many) element

Tags: react-native

I’m novice programer (i attend in bootcamp). On final project i will create some educational quiz about dropping trashes to proper recycle bins (like glas, paper, bio...etc). If you dump trash to proper bin you get point.

I found this tutorial (drag and drop in react native):
https://moduscreate.com/blog/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/

But i have problem.
How can i drop some  (trash) to proper  (bin) and add 1 point to score or inform user about bad action when he drop trash to other bin?
I have problem with this code:

return gesture.moveY > dz.y && gesture.moveY < dz.y + dz.height;

How drow  dimensions and compare it with dragging trash?

my example: https://iv.pl/image/GrbesFI

Bstregards.
Peter.

Comment: Hi Peter. You should provide us with your code, so that we can take look at it and see where it needs to be changed. See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    PanResponder,
    Animated,
    Dimensions
    } from "react-native";

    import React, {Component} from "react";
    import styles from './styles/style.js';

export default class Viewport extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
  showDraggable   : true,
  dropZoneValues  : null,
  pan             : new Animated.ValueXY(),
  result: 'nic',
  width: '',
  height: '',
  x: '',
  y: ''
};

this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null,{
    dx: this.state.pan.x,
    dy: this.state.pan.y
  }]),
  onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
    if(this.isDropZone(gesture)){
      this.setState({
        showDraggable : false,
        result: 'super!'
      });
    }else{
      Animated.spring(
      this.state.pan,
      {toValue:{x: 0,y:0}}
      ).start();
      }
     }
   });
 }

    isDropZone(gesture){
      let dz = this.state.dropZoneValues;
       return gesture.moveY > dz.y && gesture.moveY < dz.y + dz.height;

 }

 setDropZoneValues(event){
   this.setState({
     dropZoneValues: event.nativeEvent.layout
    });
 }
 onLayout = (e) => {
   this.setState({
    width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
    height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
     x: e.nativeEvent.layout.x,
  y: e.nativeEvent.layout.y
   })
  }

render(){
  return (
 <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <View style={styles.filler}/>
     <View style={styles.logo}>
     <Text>Title</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.bins}>
         <View style={styles.bins__wrapper} >
           <Text style={styles.category}>Metals</Text>
        <Text style={styles.category}>Glas</Text>
        <Text style={styles.category}>Papier</Text>
        <Text style={styles.category} onLayout={this.onLayout}>Mix</Text>
        <Text style={styles.category}  onLayout={this.setDropZoneValues.bind(this)}>           </Text>
        <Text style={styles.category}>Others</Text>
       </View>
     </View>


  <View style={styles.trash}></View>
  <View style={styles.scores}><Text>{this.state.result}
    {this.state.x} {this.state.y}</Text></View>

  {this.renderDraggable()}
</View>

  );
 }

 renderDraggable(){
   if(this.state.showDraggable){
    return (
    <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
      <Animated.View
      {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), styles.circle]}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Trash1</Text>
      </Animated.View>

    </View>
    );
    }
   }
 }
```